# What is the advantage of using arrayWithCapacity

Tags: ios, objective-c

`arrayWithCapacity` is a method defined in **NSArray.h** and implemented in **NSArray.m**

When I look at the code that [GNUStep](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnustep/gnustep-base/master/Source/NSArray.m) provided, I can get that `arrayWithCapacity` is a normal method that calls `initWithCapacity`:

```
+ (id) arrayWithCapacity: (NSUInteger)numItems
{
    return AUTORELEASE([[self allocWithZone: NSDefaultMallocZone()]
    initWithCapacity: numItems]);
}
```

And `initWithCapacity` is a simple method that only does self initialization.

```
- (id) initWithCapacity: (NSUInteger)numItems
{
  self = [self init];
  return self;
}
```

Nothing about memory allocation with number of items executed.
What is the advantage of using the `arrayWithCapacity` method? Is it better to simply use `[[NSArray alloc] init]`?

Comment: Your source is not correct. Since `NSArray` is an immutable object, it doesn't have `initWithCapacity:` method.

Comment: @Desdenova: Actually, the source is correct: that files contains both `NSArray` *and* `NSMutableArray` which is where you'll find both methods.

Comment: @DarkDust whether it's under mutable array or array implementation, I hardly think that `initWithCapacity:` only contains `[self init]`.  Between official documentation and an open source documentation, I'd go with the official one.

Comment: @Desdenova: Of course, especially since it can change from version to version, but that doesn't make the GNUStep implementation wrong. It only has `initWithCapacity:` on `NSMutableArray`, as it's supposed to be. Also consider that the capacity is a _hint_: an implementation may ignore it. Which GNUStep does.

Comment: @Desdenova: Also, [CFMutableArrayCreate](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFArray.c) _does_ ignore the capacity. And according to the [article](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/collections.html#should_i_use_arraywithcapacity) linked in azsromej answer, it looks like the same is true for `NSMutableArray` (not surprisingly in light of `CFMutableArrayCreate`).

Comment: It's defined in NSArray.h, but in interface NSMutableArray (NSMutableArrayCreation).
You can check it.

Comment: Take a look at GNUstep's GSArray.m. GNUstep's implementation isn't ignoring the given cap. When you allocate the array you get a subclass not NSMutableArray itself. Also check the comment above the -initWithCapacity: you've copied as it explains all this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expectation is that providing an explicit size improves memory allocation as there's no need to adjust the size of the array as items are added. In practice, it is just a hint and there's some evidence that it's not actually used (see this [objc.io article](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/collections.html#should_i_use_arraywithcapacity) on The Foundation Collection Classes).

Comment: So we close this, the test results shows that there is no difference in performance.
The main usage of arrayWithCapacity method is to be a "hint".
To make the code more readable, to show the programmer about how much item in the array.

Answer (score 2):

The methods are actually part of `NSMutableArray`, not `NSArray`.

It gives the implementation a hint about how many items you like to store so it can already allocate enough memory up-front instead of growing the memory as-needed, which can be expensive as it might involve allocating, copying from the old memory to the new one, deallocate old memory. And if you add a lot of items this growing might happen a lot, so it's more efficient if the `NSMutableArray` can allocate the required amount of memory in one go.

Remember that it's just a hint and an implementation may ignore it. In fact, [`CFArray/CFMutableArray`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFArray.c) *does* ignore the capacity *when creating a mutable array*:

```
static CFArrayRef __CFArrayInit(CFAllocatorRef allocator, UInt32 flags, CFIndex capacity, const CFArrayCallBacks *callBacks) {
    struct __CFArray *memory;
    UInt32 size;
    ...
    switch (__CFBitfieldGetValue(flags, 1, 0)) {
        case __kCFArrayImmutable:
            size += capacity * sizeof(struct __CFArrayBucket);
            break;
        case __kCFArrayDeque:
        case __kCFArrayStorage:
            break;
    }
    ...
    return (CFArrayRef)memory;
}

CFMutableArrayRef CFArrayCreateMutable(CFAllocatorRef allocator, CFIndex capacity, const CFArrayCallBacks *callBacks) {
    ...
    return (CFMutableArrayRef)__CFArrayInit(allocator, __kCFArrayDeque, capacity, callBacks);
}
```

According to [this article](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/collections.html#should_i_use_arraywithcapacity) linked by @azsromej, `NSMutableArray` also seems to ignore the hint.

Answer (score 1):

This applies to `NSMutableArray` since `NSArray` does not have the method `arrayWithCapacity`, this also applies to `initWithCapacity`:

There is a negligible if any advantage to using `arrayWithCapacity` from a run-time POV. It can be considered a premature optimization.

It does have a disadvantage or taking some time and/or code to come up with a value that very rarely provides a meaningful time advantage and increases the mental load.

It is also considered a hint and may or not be used, that is an implementation detail Apple can change at any tine.

Note: I have made timing tests with and without the capacity hint and the time saved, if any, was a extremely small percentage.

Also see [ridiculousfish](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html) for more information on `NSArray`.

Comment by @bbum: "the docs simply state establishes the initial capacity not that the array has allocated memory to hold all of that capacity. Array's backing store are not linearly allocated chunks of memory and the details change with the size of the array."

Comment: It's really difficult to test the performance implications of such low level components. The performance of each of these methods can vary based on countless factors, such as number of items in the array, parallel iteration, item replacement, array allocation, array release, etc. I recommend looking for an in-depth test, or official statement from Apple.

Comment: @Mabedan: This is _trivial_ to performance test! And of course the difference would be dependent on the number of elements.